# Custom render modelformset in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have two models with an OneToMany relationship

models:

```
class Proveedor(models.Model):
      id_proveedor = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
      nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=False,null=False)
      codigo_asignado =  models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False,null=False)
      class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "Proveedor"

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.nombre

class Codigo_Corto(models.Model):
      id_codigo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      id_proveedor = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor,db_column='id_proveedor', verbose_name='Proveedor')
      codigo = models.CharField(max_length=15)
      tarifa = models.IntegerField()
      revenue = models.IntegerField()
      moneda = models.CharField(max_length=2)
      direccion = models.CharField(max_length=2,blank=True,null=True)
```

I want to create a template with one only choicefield widget to select the provider (proveedor) and an html where the user type remaining fields from the model "Codigo_Corto"

Forms:

```
class CodigoCortoForm(forms.ModelForm):
      id_proveedor = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Proveedor.objects.all().order_by('nombre'),required=True,label='Proveedor')
      codigo = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'style': 'width:80px'}))
      tarifa = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'style': 'width:80px'}),required=True)
      revenue = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'style': 'width:80px'}),required=True)
      moneda = forms.ChoiceField(
               choices = (
                          ('$',"$"),('L',"L"),
                          ),
               widget = forms.Select(attrs={'style': 'width:50px'})
             ,required=True )
      direccion = forms.ChoiceField(
               choices = (
                          ('MT',"MT"),('MO',"MO"),('nn',"Sin Direccion"),
                          ),
               widget = forms.Select(attrs={'style': 'width:120px'})
              )
      def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
         super(CodigoCortoForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
         self.helper = FormHelper(self)

      class Meta:
            model = Codigo_Corto
```

My view:

```
def CCView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ccformset(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
    else:
       ccformset = formset_factory(CodigoCortoForm)
       form = ccformset()

    return render_to_response("codcorto.html",
                              {'form':form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This way I get an id_proveedor choifield for every row in the tabe, but I need only one id_proveedor modelchoicefield outside the table.

Or I need to render a modelchoicefield for the id_proveedor separately and pass it to the formset.

Any advice

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to create many Codigo_Corto for the same Proveedor on one page with one submit?

Comment: Yes Indeed, one Proveedor can have at least 50  Codigo_Corto (one provider have at least 50 short_codes). Ans instead of choosing the provider for every short_code I want to select the provider only one time

Comment: If you want Django to process multiple forms in one go, have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets